# Python - How to translate string 'p' from a list into variable value p

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of variable names from inspect.getargspec(function).args.  Each list item is a string of the variable names.  I need to use those string names from inside a function so that I can check if the value of the argument variables are a string or not.

Here's what i'm working with

```
@staticmethod
def boyleslaw(p, V, k):
    """pV = k
    p=pressure Pa, V=volume m^3, k=constant
    substitute letter to solve for that value
    return x"""

    #sv = countvar(gasses.boyleslaw)
    sv = 0
    if p == 'p': sv += 1
    if V == 'V': sv += 1
    if k == 'k': sv += 1
    if sv > 1:
        raise ValueError('Too Many Variables')

    if p == 'p' and sv == 1:
        x = k/V
        return x
    elif V == 'V' and sv == 1:
        x = k/p
        return x
    elif k == 'k' and sv == 1:
        x = p*V
        return x

@staticmethod
def charleslaw(V, T, k):
    """V/T = k
    V=volume m^3, T=temperature K, k=constant
    substitute letter for value to solve for
    return x"""
    #sv = countvar(gasses.charleslaw)
    sv = 0
    if V == 'V': sv += 1
    if T == 'T': sv += 1
    if k == 'k': sv += 1
    if sv > 1:
        raise ValueError('Too Many Variables')

    if V == 'V' and sv == 1:
        x = k*T
        return x
    elif T == 'T' and  sv == 1:
        x = V*k
        return x
    elif k == 'k' and sv == 1:
        x = V/T
        return x
```

I would like to wrap this process

```
sv = 0
if V == 'V': sv += 1
if T == 'T': sv += 1
if k == 'k': sv += 1
if sv > 1:
    raise ValueError('Too Many Variables')
```

into it's own count variables function to count the arguments and check if each arguments Value is a string.  What i'm going for So Far...then wall+head...

```
@staticmethod
def countvar(module):
    """Count number of Variables in args"""
    vc = 0
    alist = inspect.getargspec(module)
    for i in alist.args:
        if isinstance(i, str) == True:
            vc += 1
    return vc
```

this returns 3 when run on either function, regardless of their values, because each item in alist.args is a string.  I only want to increment the counter if the VALUE of each variable is a string, and raise ValueError if there is more than one variable. How to translate string 'p' into variable p...

EDIT: Clarification

```
boyleslaw(6886019.02, 1, k) #Solve for k
```

`inspect.getargspec(boyleslaw).args` 
returns `['p', 'V', 'k']`

i want a list `[6886019.02, 1, 'k']`

`alist[0]` = 
returns `'p'` #string name

i need `return p` #variable value

if value p is a string (in the case of which variable is chosen at call time to solve for) then increment counter for error handling

`boyleslaw(6886019.02, 1, k)` does not raise error

`boyleslaw(6886019.02, V, k)` would `raise ValueError('Too Many Variables')`

Comment: That's... not how you do this. At all.

Comment: Sorry...seems the 'teaching myself python' was removed from the post...perhaps you could share how to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you should (a) define an abstract base class which takes care of generics like checking arguments etc, and then basically just define the formula for each subclass. Additionally (b) it would probably make more sense to pass in a dictionary of "variablename" (string) -> value (float) mappings, rather than have the user pollute the variable namespace.

Comment: that's why i want to run the countvar() function from inside a function scope, to return the values of those variables while they exist...but even with a dictionary, how do i dict['p'] = p when all i have is 'p' from the list?  As I add more equations to the program, the names and number of args will change, hence the wrapper...

Answer (score 3):

When you define a function with positional arguments; each argument becomes mandatory:

```
>>> def foo(a, b, c):
...     pass
... 
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() takes exactly 3 arguments (0 given)
```

Therefore, there is no need to check that each argument was passed, as Python will take care of this for you.

For your second part, it is not clear what you want. First, you are checking if the name of the variable matches the value that is passed `if V == 'V'`, then you apply a formula to it that won't do what you think, as you can't multiply two strings together.

```
>>> V = 'V'
>>> T = 'T'
>>> k = 'k'
>>> x = k*T
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

So what I think you really want is to attempt to do the calculation *with numbers* and if that fails, raise an appropriate error.

For that, you can try this:

```
try:
   V = int(V)
except ValueError:
   return "Sorry, V must be a number not %s" % V
```

Add this check for each argument you are expecting. This will ensure that you only have numbers and then you mathematical calculations will work.

If you know that one of the values passed in must be a float (that is, with a decimal point); then convert it with `float()`, otherwise you'll get another surprise:

```
>>> int('12.4')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12.4'
>>> float('12.4')
12.4
```

Edit:

So after your clarification, I think what you want is this:

```
def boyleslaw(variables,solvefor='k'):
    # Normalize stuff
    variables_passed = {k.lower():v for k,v in variables.iteritems()}
    solve_for = k.lower()

    if not len(variables) or len(variables) == 1:
        return "Sorry, you didn't pass enough variables"

    if solve_for in variables_passed:
        return "Can't solve for %s as it was passed in" % solvefor
```

This method takes a dictionary as variables; and by default solves for `k`. You would call it like this:

```
d = {'V': 12, 't': 45}
boyleslaw(d) # default, solve for k

d = {'t': 45, 'k': 67}
boyleslaw(d,'V') # solve for V

d = {'t':1}
boyeslaw(d) # results in error "Didn't pass enough variables"

d = {'t': 45, 'k': 67}
boyleslaw(d) # results in error "Can't solve for k because k was passed in"
```

Comment: This way will help when I'm collecting lots of different equations of data for a project...:D  Thank you as well!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution:

```
def boyleslaw(p=None, V=None, k=None):
    """Given two of the values p, V or k this method
    returns the third according to Boyle's Law."""
    assert (p is None) + (V is None) + (k is None) == 1, \
        "exactly 2 of p, V, k must be given"
    if p is None:
        return 1.0 * k / V
    elif V is None:
        return 1.0 * k / p
    elif k is None:
        return 1.0 * p * V
```

This function first asserts that you have provided it with exactly 2 of the three quantities. Then it returns the third quantity. So you do not have to tell this function explicitly for which quantity to solve, because this is obvious from the given quantities.

```
print boyleslaw(p=2, V=3)        # 6.0
print boyleslaw(V=2)             # -> AssertionError
print boyleslaw(p=2, V=3, k=4)   # -> AssertionError
```

Comment: this way works well...and most thanks for how to make variable quantities into decimals/floats...that's going to make my life less complicated...

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you're looking for is the [exec](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) statement.  You can do something like `exec("p='a string'")`.  You should now be able to call `p` and expect `'a string'`

Comment: I just started playing with this function...found some new toys...:D  Thanx